# "Wedding anniversary" in Jewish thought.

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, calendar, wedding

Does the concept of "wedding anniversary" specifically enter Jewish thought or is it to be thought of as another of the many occasions for giving thanks to HKB"H?

Comment: "תואר כלה מאד נתעלה בקבלת יום זה עשרת הדברים"

Answer (score 4):

It seams like in Chabad they celebrate anniversaries. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16011&pgnum=295

Comment: My Yiddish is not so wonderful. Could you please direct me to the important part of the text on that page?

Comment: My rough translation - In the left column, 3 lines from the end - "in addition, this Shabbath comes in the middle of special days, that were "revealed" in the last few generations." In the right column, at line 9: "that a wedding anniversary day is indeed a main and important day in the life of a Jew, and naturally moreso in that of a "נשיא" in Israel." Basically regarding a wedding anniversary as a special day.