# Are anniversaries celebrated in Adar I or Adar II?

Tags: calendar, wedding, home-house, adar, leap-years

For [those who celebrate anniversaries](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13545/), or for calculating the end of [Shanah Rishonah](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.24.5), if a couple gets married in Adar of a non-leap-year, when is the anniversary celebrated in a leap year? Is it in the second Adar, [like Bar and Bas Mitzvos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89030/bar-mitzvah-for-child-born-in-adar)? Or is it in the first Adar, [like a yahrtzeit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68102/what-is-the-halacha-regarding-adar-yahrtzeits)?

As per [Rambam, Hilchos Milchamos 7:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.7.10) that Shanah Rishonah applies to the other exemptions from war as well (i.e. one who builds a house or plants a vineyard), my question can be extended to those cases as well.

Comment: ושמח מנין ימים של ושמח חייב בתשמיש המטה בשנה שהן כל ימות השנה חוץ מיה״כ - The Ba'al Haturim (Devarim 24:5, the passuk of Shana Rishona) seems to understand Shana Rishona ends at 354 days from when you get married.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Not sure we can pasken off Ba'al HaTurim; after all, in any year but a shaleim non-leap year, his remez fails, even before we consider Adar.